# iOS game-world calendar/clock

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an iOS game that needs to have an in-game "calendar" and day/night cycle. I envision a complete "24 hours" to take maybe 15 minutes real-world time (for example). Previously, I've used an  `int` counter for time of day.

How can I efficiently track a game-world calendar?

I figure I could at least use the time of the day counter, and every time it resets, I can increment a `day` counter, and every 7 days I can increment a `week`, and so on.

Or it might be worth using an `epoch`-like system and just converting to a readable format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 24 fake hours to take 15 real minutes, you can convert your `NSTimeInterval`s like so:

```
NSTimeInterval real = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval fake = real * 96.0; // There are 96 fake minutes for each real minute.
```

You could record your game world's start time to `NSUserDefaults` and use this offset in `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date]` instead, if you choose.

Comment: Do you think there's any benefit to this method over just faking an epoch? It can start at 0 when the user begins the game, each game loop can increment the count, and I can calculate the years/days/etc when needed?

Comment: You'll be processor-limiting your game if you're counting ticks instead of using your clock. This will cause your game to run at different speeds on different processors under different system loads. I recommend using your clock instead.

Comment: Wouldn't your example be in seconds? "96 fake seconds per every real second" considering the epoch is in seconds?

Comment: If there are 96 fake seconds for every real second, doesn't that also mean there are 96 fake minutes for every real minute? ;)